# Prime Number Determination Javascript

Tags: javascript, primes

I am creating a external javascript file. This is for homework. What I am supposed to do is determine if the number that the user enters in is a prime number or not, and displays a message if it is a prime number or not. I have my code written, compiles and everything. But I am cannot seem to figure out with, no matter what number i enter in, the display message always says that that number is a prime number. Can anyone help? Here is my code:

```
var UI; 
var TV;

var HITS;

UI = window.prompt("Enter a whole number to test as a prime number: \n", "0");
TV = parseInt(UI, 10);

var DD = TV;            //still produces same error
HITS = 0;

while (DD > 0)
{
if (TV % DD === 0)
{
    HITS++;

}       
else
{
    DD--;
}
}

if (HITS > 2)
{
document.write(UI + " is a NOT prime number");
}
else
{
document.write(UI + " is a prime number");
}
```

Comment: `var DD = TV;` evaluates to `DD = undefined;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should set the `var DD = TV;` after the `TV = parseInt(UI, 10)`.

And you should decrement DD in the while loop, if you don't want it to be infinite.

Here is the code corrected

```
var UI = window.prompt("Enter a whole number to test as a prime number: \n", "0");
var TV = parseInt(UI, 10);
var HITS = 0;
var DD = TV;
while (DD > 0) {
    if (TV % DD === 0) {
        HITS++;
    }
    DD--;
}

if (HITS > 2) {
    document.write(UI + " is a NOT prime number");
} else {
    document.write(UI + " is a prime number");
}
```

Comment: I just tried that as well, and I am still getting the same error

Comment: that works. awesome! thank you very much. such a silly mistake that i made. didn't even catch that.