# JavaScript, ask user to insert a number and judge if it's prime

Tags: javascript, primes

I just can't figure out where the problem is to ask user to insert a number and judge if it's prime, it will be great help since it's my second day learning JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prime Checker</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
var i; result = true;
var n1 = prompt("Please insert a number, I'll check if it's a prime!" , "");
n1 = Number(n1);
if(isNaN(n1))
{
    alert("You didn't insert a number, please check again!");
}
else
{
    alert("I will check right now");
}
for(i = 2; i < n1; i++)
{
   if(n1 % i == 0)
    {
    result = false;
    break;
    }
}
if(result == true)
{
alert(n1 "is a prime");
}
else
{
alert(n1 "is not a prime")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please just search through existing answers next time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837655/prime-number-determination-javascript

Comment: Why do you think that there is a problem? What happens when you try it? Do you get any error message?

Comment: You do realise you only have to check from i=2 to i=floor(sqrt(n1)), don't you?

Comment: hi all, sorry it's my syntax error, thanks for the information you provide! also I've searched related question in advance but fail to fix since it's syntax error. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an awesome tool called [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that will help - also I recommend using Chrome dev tools or Firebug for Firefox.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dR2F2/1/) is a JS Fiddle that works - you were very close.  The problem is that your JS didn't even compile.  You had a couple of lines near the end:

```
alert(n1 "is not a prime")
```

should be

```
alert(n1 + " is not a prime")
```

Also you still execute your for loop even if isNan is true.

Comment: Hi SB, really appreciate your help and shame for my syntax error...

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error. This:

```
alert(n1 "is a prime");
```

should be:

```
alert(n1 + " is a prime");
```

Same for the other alert.

Comment: Hi Guffa, thanks for your help! Really sorry for asking such a syntax error.