# Issue with prime number test javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm a beginner and trying to complete a prime number test but I'm running into an issue. Here is what I have:

```
var n = Number(prompt("Input the number you want to check for prime:"));
var i;


if (n < 2) {
    alert(n + " is not a prime number.");
}
for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
        alert(n + " is not a prime number.");
        break;
    }

    else {
        alert(n + " is a prime number."); 
        break;
    }
}
```

It's running correctly except an alert won't pop up if I input 3 or 2 and any number with a 3 in it is coming back as a prime number even if it isn't. Other than that all of my tests have worked.

Comment: 2 and 3 are both prime, and the issue is the way you've structured your loop. It's breaking out of the loop the first time through since you break inside of the else as well. What should happen instead is the final statement should be out of the loop. You'll also have to quit the check entirely, so I recommend either a) wrapping it as a function so you can `return`, or b) setting a flag instead of immediately alerting, so `isPrime = true; break;`, then later on, check if `isPrime === true`.

Comment: That's because you have not tested all the divisors when you announce `n` is prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh, your problem is the way you've structured the loop. You're breaking out regardless of if the check's completed.

```
var n = Number(prompt("Input the number you want to check for prime:"));
var i;
var isPrime = true;

if (n < 2) {
    isPrime = false;
} else if (n < 4 && n >= 2) {
    // isPrime is already true
} else if (n % 2 === 0) {
    isPrime = false; // no divisor of 2 can be prime
} else {
  var sqrtN = Math.sqrt(n);
  for (var i = 3; i <= sqrtN; i = i + 2) {
      if (n % i === 0) {
          // Only break out of the loop if a match is found
          isPrime = false;
          break;
      }
  }
}
if (isPrime) {
    alert(n + " is a prime number.");
} else {
    alert(n + " is not a prime number.");
}
```

Or, a perhaps more organized solution:

```
function isPrime (n) {
  n = parseInt(n);
  var i;
  if (Number.isNaN(n)) {
    return false;
  } else if (n < 2) {
    // 1 is not prime
    return false;
  } if (n < 4) {
    // 2 and 3 are prime, so why not skip checking them?
    return true;
  } else if (n % 2 === 0) {
    // No number divisible by 2 is prime.
    return false;
  } else {
    // This won't change, so calculate it once as suggested by Weather Vane.
    var sqrtN = Math.sqrt(n);
    // 4, 6, 8... All divisible by 2, and would be caught by initial check.
    for (i = 3; i < sqrtN; i = i + 2) { 
      // Not a prime if it's evenly divisible. 
      if (n % i === 0) {
        return false; 
      }
   }
   // Otherwise prime.
   return true; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Even better would be a) calculate the square root once only, b) check for `2` specifically, c) skip even divisors with `for (var i = 3; i <= rootn; i += 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Of course. If `n % i` is not `0`, it means that `i` does not divide `n`, but it does not mean `n` is prime. You must check all `i` in order to say that.

Moreover, don't recalculate expensive `Math.sqrt(n)` at each iteration. And be aware of `NaN`.

```js
var n = Number(prompt("Input the number you want to check for prime:"));
function isPrime(n) {
  if (n < 2 || !n) return false;
  for (var i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
alert(n + " is " + (isPrime(n) ? "" : "NOT ") + "a prime number.");
```

Of course, this algorithm is exponential ([pseudo-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time)). Don't use it for big `n`. Instead, see e.g. [Miller–Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) or [AKS primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test), which are polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

```
var UI = window.prompt("Enter a whole number to test as a prime number: \n", "0");
var TV = parseInt(UI, 10);
var HITS = 0;
var DD = TV;
while (DD > 0) {
    if (TV % DD === 0) {
        HITS++;
    }
    DD--;
}

if (HITS > 2) {
    document.write(UI + " is a NOT prime number");
} else {
    document.write(UI + " is a prime number");
}
```

Please have reference to old questions asked in stackoverflow
[link to the old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837655/prime-number-determination-javascript)

Comment: When checking for primes, you only need to check up to the square root of the number, just a tip